# How to use multple @Path parameter in GET of retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to pass mutiple parameters run time in retrofit get method for my android project. Following is my URL

http://myservice.com/home/MobileAPI/MobAPI.svc/LoginCriteria/26/address/1/permenant

Here I am using base URL as:  http://myservice.com/home/MobileAPI/MobAPI.svc

I want to pass 'address' and 'permenant' at run time in my GET method using Retrofit.

I am trying it as:

```
@GET("LoginCriteria/26/{address}/1/{permenant}")
void getDetails(@Path("address") String address,@Path("permenant") String permenant, Callback<AddressParser> parserCallback);
```

Here is my JSON response:

```
{
   "response": {
       "type": "success",
       "data": {
       "datalist": {
           "total": "20",
           "user": [
               {
                   "empcode": "",
                   "companycode": "",
                   "companyname": ""
               },
                                   {
                   "empcode": "",
                   "companycode": "",
                   "companyname": ""
               }
                                   ]
                                           }
                           }
                           }
}
```

I'm getting the following execption :

> Inside failure com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of
>   START_OBJECT token.

If I only pass one parameter at runtime it works. It is not working for more than one @Path parameter. Any suggestion  will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Can  you show your AddressParser class

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not related to your path parameters.
I am sure it is somehow related to the response of your request.

Enable logging on retrofit and check the called url and the given response.

The exception says that jackson could not parse the response of your request.

Comment: I am getting response also and it is valid. But it is going to failure method of retrofit. If I had hard coded parameter then it works perfectly. Thanks